# distributive law of vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$,$W$,$F$ be subspaces of vector space $L$.
I want to find examples of subspaces $V$,$W$,$F$ , which do not satisfy

（$V$＋$W$）∩ $F$ ＝（ $V$∩$F$）＋（$W$∩$F$） （distributive law）

Are there good examples?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean $(V+W) \cap F = (V \cap F) + (W \cap F)$? Yours does not look like a distributive law.

Comment: Thank you.I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Let $k$ be the field that you are working with and take $L=k^2$, $V=k\times\{0\}$, $W=\{0\}\times k$, and $F=\{(x,x)\mid x\in k\}$. Then $F\cap V=F\cap W=0_L$.